# Digital piano/keyboard under $1000 tuned to 432 hz with weighted keys?

Tags: piano, tuning, digital-piano

I am relatively new to piano and looking to invest in a digital piano or keyboard with weighted keys that I can tune to 432 hz. 
One more thing I have noticed that I sing better in lower octaves. So is there a piano with 88 keys that'd replace the higher most octave with one lower?

Comment: Just because you *sing* better lower has little bearing on a piano being capable of playimg lower notes! The two phenomena are not connected at all. Changing key is way more useful. And tuning to A=432Hz is pretty well inconsequential as far as your singing is concerned. There are other questions you need to ask that may shed light on what I am saying.

Comment: Also, my 2 cents about it: 432Hz is nonsense in music history, it's a lysergic trip mixed with esoteric marketing. Play in 415~418Hz, much more satisfying, as our baroque colleagues really did in the past.

Comment: @RodrigoB.Furman - surely that's the same as playing a piece written in, say, F, and playing it in (I guess) Eb?

Comment: The transposition proposed by Tim might not be overly helpful for a piano player unable to do it mentally, since then a modified score is required.

Comment: @Tim - 415 Hz is pretty exactly a half step below A=440, so F sounds in E.

Comment: @guidot - most digital pianos have a convenient transpose button!

Comment: If your voice reaches down to the lowest octave on a standard piano, you're one heckuva contra-bass

Comment: @ScottWallace - thanks - it was the principle that I was trying to make, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @RodrigoB.Furman - yes, 432 is a trip.  You're probably aware that 432 is the frequency of the Universe (because it's a pretty number, 2x2x2x2x3x3x3).  And that 440 is a brainwashing frequency introduced by the Rockefellers, or maybe the Nazis.  Lol.  Or not.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - the deepest bass voice I've ever heard, who really had a strong centered note at the pitch, sang an A below cello C.  That's still an octave above the lowest note of a standard concert grand piano.  So yeah.

Comment: tbh, if you can sing off either end of a piano, let alone both, there's little we can do to help. For everyone else, there's ***transposition*** ;)

Comment: @ScottWallace you know this story is fairytale for adulteens, don’t ya? There’s not something as “frequency of Universe”.

Comment: @RodrigoB.Furman - yes, I'm well aware of the silliness of 432.  If anyone wants a really good resource on this bizarre conspiracy theory, which at least doesn't involve killing people, check out miltonline's in-depth study: http://www.miltonline.com/2014/01/07/hertz-so-good/

Answer (score 3):

Any decent digital piano these days can be tuned any way you want, shift octaves, split the keyboard in two or more sections, etc.

What instead changes quite a bit from one model to the next is the quality of the weighed keys system, and secondarily, the quality of the internal sound samples.

Therefore, if it were for me, I would want to personally try the touch of as many different models as possible, and that would be my main criterion of choice. Everything else, i.e. everything digital rather than mechanical, these days can be easily customized in any way you want.

Comment: To cover some of the comments under the question, mentioning of *transpose* functionality might be a welcome addition.

Answer (score 1):

No need to spend as much as $1000!

If you have a Mac, I would recommend investing in a decent MIDI keyboard (prioritizing touch and feel), an audio interface, and software that allows you to use many different piano and keyboard samples.

- For the keyboard, I would visit a music store in person and try them out until you find one whose touch you like. At the $400 price point, you'll be able to find one with built-in speakers as well, so you can practice without plugging into the computer, too. If that doesn't matter to you, there are plenty of options in the $200 range.
- For the audio interface, I'd recommend the Focusrite Scarlett Solo, which runs about $120. You can also use this to record guitar, bass, or vocals if you want that.
- For software, the app GarageBand has plenty of samples built in, so you try using that first and see if it doesn't satisfy you. If you want more sounds, Mainstage is basically just the Logic sample library without the production capabilities, and it costs $30. The full Logic program runs $200, and I think it's overkill for your purposes.

Total cost: about $400-600, and you have a rig that you can upgrade piece by piece as your interests evolve.